# show/hide divs based on radio button selection using jquery in mvc5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a MVC5 application and trying to hide/show divs based on the selection of radio buttons. below is my HTML code and script which seems not to be working for some reasons that I don't understand.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#panel1").click(function () {
            $("#p1").show(600);
            $("#p2").hide();
        });
        $("#panel2").click(function () {
            $("#p1").hide(600);
            $("#p2").show();
        });
   });
</script>

<div class="radio">
    <label> <input type="radio" name="search" value="Student" id="panel1"checked>Student</label>
    <label>  <input type="radio" name="search" value="Employee" id="panel2">Employee</label>
</div>

<div class="container" id="p1">
    <p>Div one opened</p>
</div>

<div class="container" id="p2" hidden>
    <p>Div two opened</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You code works fine, are you sure you have included jquery correct?

Comment: its working fine now , i have included the jquery file             <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add Jquery file, add jquery cdn at the top

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#panel1").click(function () {
            console.log("click");
            $("#p1").show(600);
            $("#p2").hide();
        });
        $("#panel2").click(function () {
            $("#p1").hide(600);
            $("#p2").show();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="radio">
    <label> <input type="radio" name="search" value="Student" id="panel1"checked>Student</label>
    <label>  <input type="radio" name="search" value="Employee" id="panel2">Employee</label>
</div>

<div class="container" id="p1">
    <p>Div one opened</p>
</div>

<div class="container" id="p2" hidden>
    <p>Div two opened</p>
</div>
```

Comment: and how do i get the selected value from the radio button and use it to my mvc5 controller